# Segmentation fault while using array of function pointers in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char c;
    enum state_t {
        state1,
        state2,
        state3
    } states;
    enum state_t (*action[3])(char c);

    state=state1;
    initialize_state(action);
}

void initialize_state (enum state_t  (*action[])(char c))
{
    action[state1]=func1;
    action[state2]=func2;
    action[state3]=func3;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault at `initialize_state(action);`.

Comment: I don't think `state_t` can be a local type if you want to have a function return it. Try making it global.

Comment: In fact, as it stands, this doesn't even compile. Please post a proper, well tested piece of code that accurately represents your problem.

Comment: `state` is a typo, should read `states` I guess

Answer (score 2):

Since a segfault implies an illegal reference to memory, check to make sure that you're not passing an invalid function pointer address.

Have you run your code through a debugger to figure out exactly where the segfault lies? If not, I suggest you do so. Your code fragment doesn't compile as-is.

http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#arrays <-- using arrays of function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your code being a total mess, e.g. no prototype declaration and having the function declared below main, or not having a return type in int main(void) , missing void in main()...etc, I guess that you probably have declared the return types of func1, func2, func3 also erroneously. e.g. `void func1(void){}` .